# Automation scripting in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, automation

I've been making automation scripts for windows using powershell, and I am looking for an equivalent scripting language that will also fit linux os. I want it to be object-oriented, and be including all kinds of base administration commands such as those for administrating the file system. Does ruby fit these requirements?